# How to set padding in UIText view

Tags: iphone

Any clue on how to set padding on left/right/top/bottom of a UITextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with this set of code:

```
self.myTextView.pagingEnabled = YES;
UIEdgeInsets aUIEdge = [self.myTextView contentInset]; 
aUIEdge.left = 30;
aUIEdge.right = 30;
aUIEdge.top = 10;
aUIEdge.bottom = 10;

self.myTextView.contentInset = aUIEdge;
```

You will get left/right/top/bottom paddings.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm I never saw a padding property in the UITextView object. But maybe you just could do it by setting  different valu to the textView frame ;-)